# How can I reformat this array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have searched high and low and I must be overlooking something obvious. How can I reconstruct this output I have retrieved from the youtube API to look like the second code block below. Also I want to remove the videos portion of the array. I don't even know where to start or I would post some kind of example I have tried so far.

I would also like to know what is the exact terminology for how the first array is constructed vs the second.

Here is the youtube array that gets returned from our API call. It's simply 2 posts from a youtube feed.. they start under the "items": [ portion of the array.

```
Array
(
    [videos] => {
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/qYy5QZyPpmtNPAJ_cTTDagaLYv0\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 15,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/o2RZKiVOV3D5PlBUVONXwxRQACQ\"",
   "id": "VVUtU1dDTm1QOS11ODFLOC1GMkY5RlB3LmJITEwxTDlFX0pB",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-09-23T21:52:41.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC-SWCNmP9-u81K8-F2F9FPw",
    "title": "A day in the life of a sponsored skateboarder / parent",
    "description": "I've had a hard time connecting with my family lately.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bHLL1L9E_JA/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Tony Hawk",
    "playlistId": "UU-SWCNmP9-u81K8-F2F9FPw",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "bHLL1L9E_JA"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/tFkAXp2IF-WC4lWu_OsWEF4mLIk\"",
   "id": "VVUtU1dDTm1QOS11ODFLOC1GMkY5RlB3LkwzdHZvTnBBc25J",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-01-05T05:13:22.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC-SWCNmP9-u81K8-F2F9FPw",
    "title": "Tahitian treats",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L3tvoNpAsnI/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Tony Hawk",
    "playlistId": "UU-SWCNmP9-u81K8-F2F9FPw",
    "position": 1,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "L3tvoNpAsnI"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}

)
```

I would like to reformat it so it look more like this. I have only added a few fields for the sake of having to retype them all. Hopefully the basic idea is understood.

```
Array
(
 [data] => Array
        (
      [0] => stdClass Object
          (
             [kind] => "youtube#playlistItem",
             [etag] => "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/o2RZKiVOV3D5PlBUVONXwxRQACQ\"",
             [id] => "VVUtU1dDTm1QOS11ODFLOC1GMkY5RlB3LmJITEwxTDlFX0pB",
             [snippet] => (
                [publishedAt] =>  "2015-09-23T21:52:41.000Z",
                [channelId] =>  "UC-SWCNmP9-u81K8-F2F9FPw",
              )
           )
      [1] => stdClass Object
          (
             [kind] => "youtube#playlistItem",
             [etag] => "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/o2RZKiVOV3D5PlBUVONXwxRQACQ\"",
             [id] => "VVUtU1dDTm1QOS11ODFLOC1GMkY5RlB3LmJITEwxTDlFX0pB",
             [snippet] => (
                [publishedAt] =>  "2015-09-23T21:52:41.000Z",
                [channelId] =>  "UC-SWCNmP9-u81K8-F2F9FPw",
              )
           )
       )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I forgot to decode the json response...

json_decode($videos);

The first block of code above is a json array and the second block is the decoded version.